Binary Bomb Phase_3
I am having a very difficult time tracing the assembly code for the following binary bomb (An assignment from school where a bomb has to be defused, this bomb contains 6 phases which all have 1 correct input to proceed to the next phase). Can somebody help me find the right inputs and explain how?
I am currently on phase_3 and it has a jmp table with arithmetic done to the inputs. I have identified that the input is "%d %d" which is two integers. I know that in the end %eax must be 316 %edx must be 1 in order to solve it however, I cannot quite figure out what is being done to my two inputs.
0000000000400f58 <phase_3>:
  400f58:   48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp
  400f5c:   48 8d 4c 24 08          lea    0x8(%rsp),%rcx
  400f61:   48 8d 54 24 0c          lea    0xc(%rsp),%rdx
  400f66:   be 1e 27 40 00          mov    $0x40271e,%esi
  400f6b:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400f70:   e8 bb fc ff ff          callq  400c30 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
  400f75:   83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
  400f78:   7e 16                   jle    400f90 <phase_3+0x38>
  400f7a:   8b 44 24 08             mov    0x8(%rsp),%eax
  400f7e:   83 7c 24 0c 07          cmpl   $0x7,0xc(%rsp)
  400f83:   77 73                   ja     400ff8 <phase_3+0xa0>
  400f85:   8b 54 24 0c             mov    0xc(%rsp),%edx
  400f89:   ff 24 d5 00 25 40 00    jmpq   *0x402500(,%rdx,8)
  400f90:   e8 3f 07 00 00          callq  4016d4 <explode_bomb>
  400f95:   eb e3                   jmp    400f7a <phase_3+0x22>
  400f97:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  400f9a:   ba 10 00 00 00          mov    $0x10,%edx
  400f9f:   eb 05                   jmp    400fa6 <phase_3+0x4e>
  400fa1:   ba 20 00 00 00          mov    $0x20,%edx
  400fa6:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  400fa9:   d1 fa                   sar    %edx
  400fab:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  400fae:   d1 fa                   sar    %edx
  400fb0:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  400fb3:   d1 fa                   sar    %edx
  400fb5:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  400fb8:   d1 fa                   sar    %edx
  400fba:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  400fbd:   d1 fa                   sar    %edx
  400fbf:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  400fc2:   d1 fa                   sar    %edx
  400fc4:   3d 3c 01 00 00          cmp    $0x13c,%eax
  400fc9:   75 32                   jne    400ffd <phase_3+0xa5>
  400fcb:   83 fa 01                cmp    $0x1,%edx
  400fce:   75 2d                   jne    400ffd <phase_3+0xa5>
  400fd0:   48 83 c4 18             add    $0x18,%rsp
  400fd4:   c3                      retq   
  400fd5:   ba 20 00 00 00          mov    $0x20,%edx
  400fda:   eb cf                   jmp    400fab <phase_3+0x53>
  400fdc:   ba 20 00 00 00          mov    $0x20,%edx
  400fe1:   eb cd                   jmp    400fb0 <phase_3+0x58>
  400fe3:   ba 20 00 00 00          mov    $0x20,%edx
  400fe8:   eb cb                   jmp    400fb5 <phase_3+0x5d>
  400fea:   ba 20 00 00 00          mov    $0x20,%edx
  400fef:   eb c9                   jmp    400fba <phase_3+0x62>
  400ff1:   ba 20 00 00 00          mov    $0x20,%edx
  400ff6:   eb c7                   jmp    400fbf <phase_3+0x67>
  400ff8:   e8 d7 06 00 00          callq  4016d4 <explode_bomb>
  400ffd:   e8 d2 06 00 00          callq  4016d4 <explode_bomb>
  401002:   eb cc                   jmp    400fd0 <phase_3+0x78>
  401004:   ba 20 00 00 00          mov    $0x20,%edx
  401009:   eb b9                   jmp    400fc4 <phase_3+0x6c>

The jump table.  This is a non-PIE executable so these are absolute addresses, no randomization of .text addresses across runs even if run outside GDB.
(gdb) x/8gx0x402500
0x402500:       0x0000000000400fe3      0x0000000000400fd5
0x402510:       0x0000000000400ff1      0x0000000000400f97
0x402520:       0x0000000000400fdc      0x0000000000400fa1
0x402530:       0x0000000000401004      0x0000000000400fea


Copy/paste disassembly as text in a code block (triple backticks), not a picture of text.  Same for the jump table dump from GDB.

I have just updated it, thanks

It range-checks the first input for EDX <= 7u, then uses it to index the jump table, so you have 8 possible locations for the switch to go.
Since you're already using GDB, you can just run it and single-step it to see what happens for some sample inputs.
Many of the switch cases jump into a sequence of edx >>= 1 (sar = arithmetic right shift) and eax += 1 (add), which ends by requiring EDX=1 and EAX=0x13c, otherwise explode.
If you text-search in the disassembly for the addresses from the jump table, you'll see the 8 possible locations where an EDX value can jump, and what the code there does.  I use the mouse to copy/paste the address (not including the leading zeros or 0x), hit control-f (or in a text terminal (KDE konsole), ctrl-shift-f), and ctrl-v if the search didn't already take my selection.  The disassembly marks addresses like 400fab:, which is why I had to omit the leading zeros to get a text match.

I know that in the end %eax must be 316 %edx must be 1 in order to solve it however, I cannot quite figure out what is being done to my two inputs.

EDX=1 jumps to 400fd5, where a mov sets EDX=0x20  (1<<5) and jumps into the sequence of sar/add instructions after the first pair, so 5 sar %edx instructions run, turning 1<<5 into 1.
Other EDX values jump to different points with the same EDX=0x20 so couldn't result in EDX=1 at the end.

So from my understanding the answer would be 311 1? With EDX=1 it jumps to the sequence of adding 1 to EAX 5 times. The end goal is having EAX=316 and EDX=1, so that would satisfy it?

@samikim: Yes.  I actually missed that you'd written "in the end", and thought you'd figured out working inputs but didn't understand why!  Turns out EDX=1 is also the correct input.  A compiler could have done a much better job of optimizing if it had set EDX=0x20 before jumping (with a different register holding the table index), so the jump-table addresses could be directly into the sar/add sequence instead of to one of many different blocks that all set EDX=0x20 and jump somewhere into that sequence.

I tried doing 311 1 as my input but it's not correct. It hit my breakpoint at explode_bomb. I inspected the registers right after it hit that breakpoint and here is what I got:
RAX = 0x1
RDX = 0x7fffffffd068

UPDATE: I tried putting a breakpoint at 0x400fab (where it jumps to) but it is skipping that breakpoint and going to my other breakpoint which is explode_bomb. Does this mean that 1 is not valid?

You got the inputs swapped. Try 1 311 instead.
